The dynamic validation I created with Formik and Yup isn't working correctly
I am trying to write a custom yup util for my project. my goal here is to make the form fields specified according to the data coming from the backend service conform to a single type or rule (eg. key-value for selectBox). For some reason, the validation I have written for the data sent by the backend in the code I wrote does not work :), it actually freezes as a yup object and the describe method also works, but it does not validate with the value values I give, I have tried different solution methods to solve the problem, but I have not been able to solve the problem. I would like help from you on this issue, if there is something wrong with my code or if you have any ideas, I would be very grateful, thank you in advance.
import * as yup from 'yup';

const defaultValidationRules = (customMessage) => {
  return {
    string: yup
      .string()
      .min(1)
      .required(customMessage ?? `path is required`),
    number: yup.number().required(customMessage ?? `path is required`),
    boolean: yup.boolean().required(customMessage ?? `path is required`),
    object: yup.object().required(customMessage ?? `path is required`),
    array: yup.array().required(customMessage ?? `path is required`)
  };
};

const createValidationSchema = (backendDependencies) => {
  const shape = {};

  if (Array.isArray(backendDependencies)) {
    backendDependencies.forEach((dependency) => {
      const { path, data, rule, customRule, customMessage, objectPathField } = dependency;

      const subShape = {};

      if (Array.isArray(data)) {
        data.forEach((item) => {
          if (customRule) {
            subShape[item[objectPathField]] = customRule;
          } else {
            subShape[item[objectPathField]] = defaultValidationRules(customMessage)[rule];
          }
        });
      } else {
        Object.keys(data).forEach((item) => {
          if (customRule) {
            subShape[item] = customRule;
          } else {
            subShape[item] = defaultValidationRules(customMessage)[rule];
          }
        });
      }

      shape[path] = yup.object().shape(subShape);
    });
  } else {
    const { path, data, rule, customRule, customMessage, objectPathField } = backendDependencies;
    const subShape = {};

    if (Array.isArray(data)) {
      data.forEach((item) => {
        if (customRule) {
          subShape[item[objectPathField]] = customRule;
        } else {
          subShape[item[objectPathField]] = defaultValidationRules(customMessage)[rule];
        }
      });
    } else {
      Object.keys(data).forEach((item) => {
        if (customRule) {
          subShape[item] = customRule;
        } else {
          subShape[item] = defaultValidationRules(customMessage)[rule];
        }
      });
    }
    if (!shape[path]) {
      shape[path] = yup.object().shape(subShape);
    }
  }

  return yup.object(shape);
};

const validateForm = async (values, backendDependencies, valuesSchema, setErrors) => {
  const backendSchema = createValidationSchema(backendDependencies);
  console.log('backendSchema: ', backendSchema.describe());
  console.log('values: ', values);

  try {
    await valuesSchema.validate(values, { abortEarly: false });
    await backendSchema.validate(values, { abortEarly: false });

    return null;
  } catch (err) {
    const errors = {};
    if (err.inner) {
      err.inner.forEach((error) => {
        errors[error.path] = error.message;
      });
    }

    setErrors(errors);
    return errors;
  }
};

export default validateForm;


The code I have written is as above and you can see the following example for usage example
   validateForm(
      values,
      {
        path: 'lawControlClauses',
        data: controlClauses,
        rule: 'boolean',
        objectPathField: 'value'
      },
      legalUnitReviewNewSchema,
      formikLegalUnitReview.setErrors
    );

